# Add users` extra data to firestore when they sign in first time with web Firebase firestore

Tags: reactjs, web, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
unsubscribeFromAuth = null; //memory leak

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: user });
      if (user === null)
        return;

      // user data
      const uid = user.uid;
      const photoURL = user.photoURL;
      const name = user.displayName;      

      const userRef = firestore.collection('Users');
      userRef.where('uid','==',uid).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("uid size : ",querySnapshot.size);
        // add user extra data when first sign in.
        if (querySnapshot.size === 0) {
          firestore.collection('Users').add({
            uid: uid,
            photoURL: photoURL,
            name: name,
          })
          .then((docRef) => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

My code is like this.
But when I sign in, **querySnapshot.size is 0** and it add user`s data **again and again** even though there are **already user data**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtQr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HTlA.png)

Like these, they have same uids but signing in made again and again.
Is there any problem when I program like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by **result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser**.
This can check the user is first sign in.

```
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {
        const user = result.user;
        const uid = user.uid;
        const name = user.displayName;
        const photoURL = user.photoURL;

        // push data when first sign in.
        console.log("first sign in user", result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
        if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            firestore.collection('Users').add({
                uid: uid,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                name: name,
            })
            .then((docRef) => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
```